# MySQL error #1054 "unknown column in field list" with trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Wondering if anyone can help.

I am using MySQL. I have two tables here in my database, `locker` and `locker_possession`. `locker_possession` is a link table to a student table that logs what lockers are owned by what student, and the `locker` table is information on each individual locker. In `locker` there is a boolean column to say whether that `locker` is taken or not. For this, I have tried to create a trigger so that when a `locker_id` from the `locker table` is referenced in `locker_possession`, the `locker_taken` boolean will turn true. The trigger is accepted by the schema and I can insert data into `locker`. However, inserting into `locker_possesion` brings up the following error:

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'locker.locker_id' in 'where clause'`

These are the create scripts for locker and locker_possession:

```
CREATE TABLE locker (  
    locker_id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    locker_taken BOOL NOT NULL,        
    deposit_paid BOOL NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (locker_id) 
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE locker_possession (
    locker_id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    owner_id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (locker_id) REFERENCES locker(locker_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES student(student_id)
);
```

These are the insert scripts:

```
INSERT INTO `locker` (`locker_id`,`locker_taken`,`deposit_paid`) VALUES  
    ("LK1","0","0"), 
    ("LK2","0","0"), 
    ("LK3","0","0"), 
    ("LK4","0","0"), 
    ("LK5","0","0"), 
    ("LK6","0","0"), 
    ("LK7","0","0"), 
    ("LK8","0","0"), 
    ("LK9","0","0"), 
    ("LK10","0","0");
```

```
INSERT INTO `locker_possession` (`locker_id`,`owner_id`) VALUES 
    ("LK2","P1"),
    ("LK4","P2"),
    ("LK5","P3"),
    ("LK7","P4"),
    ("LK8","P5");
```

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER locker_availability_update
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON locker_possession
    FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE locker
    BEGIN
    SET locker_taken = 1 WHERE locker.locker_id = NEW.locker_id;
```

If anyone has any ideas or can help in any way that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious syntax- remove the begin statement.

Comment: What happens if you remove `locker` from `WHERE` clause? something like `WHERE locker_id = NEW.locker_id`

Comment: @P.Salmon that worked a treat. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `BEGIN` is misplaced, and should have an `END`.  In MySQL, I would suggest:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER locker_availability_update
    AFTER INSERT ON locker_possession FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE locker
        SET locker_taken = 1
        WHERE locker.locker_id = NEW.locker_id;
END; $$
```